# Optimize form rendering React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i optimize 'form' rendering. For each key pressed, the component is rendered
Any idea to solve or improve it?

```
const Example = () => {
  const [inputForm, setInputForm] = useState('');
  const inputHandler = event => {
    setInputForm(event.target.value);
  };
  console.log('Rendering');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>Text: {inputForm}</span>
        <input value={inputForm} onChange={inputHandler} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[log of component rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCV0r.png)
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Uncontrolled Components, from the documentation:

https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 0):

As @andergtk mentioned, if you want to avoid rendering the input on each key press you'll have to resort to an input that React does not control.

> To write an uncontrolled component, **instead of writing an event**
>   **handler for every state update**, you can use a ref to get form values
>   from the DOM.

but the rendering on every key press that you notice is expected in the case of a controlled input where React has control over the value of the field and should not worry you

A controlled input is more *"powerful"* because you let React sync your data with your input value

more on this subject in the docs or in this article (there are lots of other resources on this): https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Answer (score 0):

improving your case is not about stop rendering, every time input value is changed it needs to be re-rendered, if not changes wouldn't apply

to improve performance you may:

- useCallback to the event handler if you gonna do calculations there
- maybe split label out of the component returning only input element
- useState may be declared outside Input component to make sense
- Input props: { value, setValue } ,. then setup callback

react renders its components based on props or state changes, so always something changes on screen react has to re-render that component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).